# Default filtering item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page like this page:
http://www.sungeetheme.com/html/our_gallery_3_colums.html

In the filtering Gallery, the default item is "all"

How do I change the default to something else on page load, for example: Portrait?

I tried to change in the code section the variable dataFilterVal from "All" to something else and it did not work well

```
var masonryFilter = {
    massMasonry: [],
    dataFilterVal: "all",
    init: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.filterEl('.j-filter', '~ .j-filter-content');
        self.masonry();
    },
    masonry: function () {
        var self = this;
        var msnry;
        var i = 0;
        $('.j-masonry').each(function () {
            var el = $(this),
                newClass = 'j-masonry-' + i;

            el.addClass(newClass).attr('data-masonry-id', i);
            i++;
            el.imagesLoaded(function () {
                var container = document.querySelector('.' + newClass);

                msnry = new Masonry(container,
                    {
                        itemSelector: '.j-masonry-item',
                        columnWidth: '.' + newClass + ' .masonry-gridSizer',
                        transitionDuration: '1.2s'
                    });
                self.massMasonry.push(msnry);
                el.data('masonry', msnry);
            });
        });
    },
    filterEl: function (filterNav, filterContent) {
        var self = this;
        $(filterNav + ' a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var el = $(this);
            var activeClass = "is-category-filter-active";
            var activeContainer = $(filterContent, $(this).parents(filterNav)).eq(0);
            console.log(activeContainer);
            $('li', $(this).parents(filterNav)).removeClass(activeClass);
            el.closest('li').addClass(activeClass);
            self.dataFilterVal = el.attr('data-filter');
            self.filterStart(self.dataFilterVal, activeContainer);
        });
    },
    filterStart: function (dataFilterVal, filterContent) {
        var self = this;
        if (dataFilterVal == "all") {
            $('[class*="j-filter-"]', filterContent).show().stop(true, false).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 400);
        } else {
            var hideItems = $('[class*="j-filter-"]', filterContent).not(dataFilterVal);
            hideItems.stop(true, false).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 400);
            setTimeout(function () {
                hideItems.hide();
            }, 301);
            $(dataFilterVal, filterContent).show().stop(true, false).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 400);
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            var masonryId = $(filterContent).find('.j-masonry').attr('data-masonry-id');
            self.massMasonry[masonryId].layout();
        }, 501);
    }
};
masonryFilter.init();
```

Comment: What did you try changing the "all" attribute to? Did you try ".j-filter-street" for example or did you just try "street"?

Comment: To .j-filter-portrait